# How can I change variable color in netbeans code completion window?

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201510222201) on MacOS for PHP development, with the new Dracula for Netbeans look & feel enabled. The problem is that variable names in code completion window are unreadable (too dark - see attached screenshot).

[image]

I've digged through the whole "Preferences / Font & colors" menu but couldn't find a solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in a recent update. The default colors of code completion in Dracula L&F are now easily readable.

[image: screenshot]